# Azure Active Directory Token Has Incorrect Audience

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm grabbing a token (using v2 enpoints) for a client app that has been exposed to an API app, all registed in Azure Active Directory. I can successfully get tokens that have the correct scopes, roles, etc., but I noticed the audience is not quite right. In the api app registration in the directory in Azure Portal, I go to the "Expose an API Blade" I have set the app id, and hovering over the info icon it says "The globally unique URI used to identify this web API. It is the prefix for scopes and in access tokens, it is the value of the audience claim. Also referred to as an identifier uri.". Mine Is something like "AppName-Prod-Api-Ad.azurewebsites.net". However, when getting an access token for this api, regardless of what scope I request, I get the client id of the api inside the token instead of the identifier uri. This isn't detrimental, but I would prefer that clients that consume my api not see my client id in their decoded token.

In v1, I could specify this identifier uri as the "resource" parameter while acquiring the token and the audience would be correct in the decoded token. This is not available in v2.

So, to summarize, I have the identifier uri set in the app registration for an API in Azure Active Directory, in Azure Portal, but the audience present in access tokens is instead the Client Id of the API, regardless of what scope I request. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Same issue here, any update? [Wrong Audience on Azure JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78182845/azure-obo-flow-produces-web-api-client-id-while-bearerstrategy-expects-azure-web)

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same thing.
It could be that MS is trying to unify behaviour and return the same audience every time regardless of how you requested the token. 
Either the doc or behaviour is wrong though.

Technically your API should still accept both audiences, client id and app ID URI. 
In v1 especially you had to configure both since a client could acquire a token using either the API client id or URI leading to different audiences. 
So I'd just accept both values as valid audiences.